# Is there a way to detect filename encoding on Windows and Linux in c++?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, encoding, utf-8

Im trying to make a crossplatform application in c++ that does character conversion. 
I have setup a conversion table in UTF-8 with the rules. eq( A = 诶). I use the boost library to get the filenames. My understanding is that I have to convert them from encoding X to UTF-8, do the conversion, convert back to encoding X and save with the new filename. how do i find out the encoding the filesystem is using?

Comment: NTFS filnames don't *have* an encoding. They're just opaque sequences of 16-bit values. Typically they're used for UTF-16, but that isn't mandated or enforced.

Comment: But i still need to know how the OS is translating those values for the user or i can not do the conversion.

Comment: NTFS has no encoding, but Windows uses UTF-16.  That's your answer for Windows.

Comment: @bluedog: That's true, but you can't generally tell whether a file was written by the Windows API or by a kernel call directly...

Comment: If NTFS doesn't have an encoding, then why does it have an `$UpCase` table listing the relation between upper- and lowercase UTF-16 codepoints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows uses UTF-16 and Linux platforms are often "binary".  By binary I mean whatever bytes you see as the filename is the filename - don't decode or re-encode the bytes.  There is no indicator to state what format they were written in, but it's generally UTF-8.

Comment: In fact you can have great "fun" with naming files in Linux with "weird" characters in them - line newline or * - especially when the user tries to delete the file *. ;)

Comment: I read there are some ways to estimate the encoding they are written in? I guess its best to just assume its UTF-8 on linux

Comment: @Ollosaurusrex, no, it's best to not assume any encoding for file names. If you have to assume some encoding, use the one set in the user's locale. You can call `nl_langinfo` to find it.